# Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent', or 'children' prop for the screen 'User'

Tags: react-native

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out what React Native's cryptic error messages mean. I've had the following error for about thirty minutes and after all my googling I still don't know how to fix it: Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent', or 'children' prop for the screen 'User'.

My App module:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Button, View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { UserDetailScreen } from './app/screens/UserDetailScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="User" component={UserDetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  console.log("test");
  console.log(UserDetailScreen);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

My UserDetailScreen

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Button, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import {styles} from '../assets/stylesheets/UserDetailStyles';

export default class UserDetailScreen extends React.Component<Props> {
  render = ({ navigation }) => {...return components}
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do in your UserDefaultScreen component? The code doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: ...return components is pseudo-code. I am rendering a user's information in this function.

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting a default class in UserDetailScreen.js. Import a default class like so: `import UserDetailScreen from './app/screens/UserDetailScreen';`